# Is it possible to do a Google Maps search for two different search criteria (e.g., Hospital and garage)?

Tags: angular7

I need to show hospitals and garages near my location on load of my application. I tried searching in google and take embed code and put it in iframe.

Comment: Hi, welcome, could you show some code?

Comment: I need hard coded embed url it is not related to coding

Comment: Well, if it's not related to coding, this question is off-topic in here

Comment: this is my hardcoded url for near by hospital search but i need both hospital and garage.how can i do that?
url- https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d31111.103842429362!2d77.61974437346018!3d12.914920654322183!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1shospitals+near+me!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1563430990299!5m2!1sen!2sin?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d31111.103697286824!2d77.61974438316184!3d12.91492182002813!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1sgarages!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1563430922217!5m2!1sen!2sin